# Adding a class to elements created by PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a datatable which I am populating using data from an MYSQL database.

In order to run jQuery commands, I need to give the elements an `id` or `class`

but get an error when I add this into the PHP code.

Code I am using:

```
<?php
    $host_name = 'xxx.hosting-data.io';
    $database = 'xxx';
    $user_name = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxx';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<select>
                      <option>".$result['tablerow']."</option>
                  </select>";
        }
    } else { 
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want to add a `class`, `id` and `name` to the select and a `value` to the option

When I try adding the class using `<select class="class">` it seems to break the site same with id and value.

Is there a better way to add such values?

Comment: FYI: Using double quotes for `<select class="class">` while being inside an already double quoted echo statement, would have thrown you a parse error. Escape the double quotes instead `\"` which will render a nicely formatted HTML double quoted syntax. In some cases and I've seen this happen before, a double quoted object is required.

Answer (score 0):

Beware the quoting here, using double quotes will confuse PHP, this will likely do what you need:

```
<select class='class'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
echo "<select>
        <option class="yourClass">".$result['tablerow']."</option>
      </select>";
```

Try using single quotes

```
 echo "<select>
            <option class='yourClass'>".$result['tablerow']."</option>
          </select>";
```